# Шансы на то / шансы того, что

Tags: согласование

Вдруг встал вопрос - а как правильно?

Хорошая реклама повысит *шансы на то, что* больше людей посетит ваше кафе.
Или "*шансы того, что*"?

Answer (score 3):

Из серии "оба хуже". 
Шанс - он либо просто чей, либо чего.

"Шанс на то" - очень специфическое что-то.

Если совсем нельзя фразу перестроить кардинально, то *"повышает шансы посещения..."*  - по управлению так, но все равно кривовато по смыслу. Тут же еще "повышает шансы" и "больше людей" - избыточность. "Увеличивает вероятность увеличения" получается. Без бутылки нематематики и не поймут. А математики поймут, но неправильно. У вас получается, что увеличение посещаемости и так происходит, без рекламы. А вот от рекламы не посетителей больше становится, а "шансов" неких. Вряд ли это тот смысл, который требуется передать.

Так что перестраивать фразу придется все равно.
***"Хорошая реклама [скорее всего] увеличит число посетителей в кафе"*** - какие еще шансы? Или тут о чем-то другом?

***"Хорошая реклама привлечет в кафе больше посетителей"*** - тоже вариант, еще лучше.

Answer (score 2):

"Шансы (чьи-то) **на** то", либо "вероятность (ничья) **того**, что...". "Шансы того" указывает на принадлежность шансов кому-то - "тому" (например, "шансы /на что-то/ того, кто принял такие-то меры"), поэтому не сочетается с "того, что...". Видимо, дело в том, что в русском "шансы" - понятие субъективное, т.е. всегда примеряемое к кому-то или к чьим-то интересам.

Answer (score 1):

Шанс - это всего лишь благоприятная ситуация для осуществления какого-либо события. Вы можете использовать хорошую рекламу, но это не гарантирует обязательный рост посетителей кафе, просто вероятность  этого события увеличивается. Поэтому, убрав  слово "шанс" из предложения, мы упрощаем то содержание, которое автор вкладывает в свое сообщение, текст становится приглаженным, но менее выразительным и экспрессивным.

Если уж править предложение, то надо исключить "два повышения" -   рост  посетителей и повышение шансов на этот рост. К примеру, так:  **Хорошая реклама - это шанс того, что больше людей посетит ваше кафе.**

ШАНС, -а; м. [франц. chance] Вероятная возможность осуществления чего-л. Иметь, использовать ш. Даю тебе ш. Упустить свой ш. Последний, единственный ш. Один ш. из ста, из тысячи. Одинаковые, равные шансы. Много, мало шансов у кого-л. **Ш. на спасение, на успех, на удачу.** Есть все шансы, что прыжок будет удачным. Не имею никаких шансов увидеть его.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

В бою один на один велик шанс того, что противник, увернувшись, перехватит инициативу и сделает из вас котлету. Шанс на то, что ее (бутылку) выловят, равен одному из миллионов, ибо миллионами исчисляется сейчас число бутылок, плавающих в океане.

Answer (score 0):

Со словом *шансы* звучит, по-моему, не очень-то. Я бы сказал *вероятность того.*